# Data binding properties are not saved during user control

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, user-controls

This is my lookup object on usercontrol

[UserControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSfZB.png)

This is my code:

```
[Bindable(true)]
public CalcEdit ToplamMiktari
{
    get { return this.TxtToplamMiktari; }
    set { this.TxtToplamMiktari = value; }
}
```

I'm using this usercontrol object on a form. I set the data field coming from the database to the Databindings property.

[Use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvuTz.png)

I save and close.

When I reopened the form, I noticed that the settings could not be saved.

[Where is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EeBy.png)

Is there anyone who has experience with this and can give me information?
Kind regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I created a usercontrol. It contains DbLookUp lists. When I set the databindings properties of these DbLookUp lists from within a form, the settings are not retained. DataBindings properties are lost at design time.

Please review the pictures.